# Can I run two LED strips in parallel?

Tags: parallel, led-strip

I'm considering bying [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Waterproof-Strip-Lights-Kitchen-Lighting/dp/B00QKF1MWE) LED strip for better lighting around the bathroom mirror, but I'd like to cut it into 1/3 and 2/3 and arrange them in parallel. Is that possible with the given parts? Electrically I mean, physically I'm quite capable of soldering and mounting.

I ask because I'm unsure what effect the parallel connection will have on the power supply and light output. I haven't bought the thing yet, but there are no relevant hints on the web shop page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.  The LEDs in the strip are in parallel, so you can cut it and use it parallel as well.  However, make sure that you only cut at the marked positions.

Comment: I sort of expected this answer, and should probably have included more words in my question. Thing is -- as far as I can tell, these strips are not all-lights-in-parallel, but a series (of sets of 3).

Comment: Correct.  The strips are made of groups of three LEDs in series.  The groups are then in parallel.  You can only cut the strips at the marked spots between groups.  Well, you could cut them at other places, but then the LEDs for that group won't work at all.